# how to extract contents of a file that match {START}..<xyz>..{END} but it should contain xyz

Tags: python, awk, sed

I have a file that contain:

```
{START}
..
<xyz>
..
{END}
{START}
...
xyz
...
...
{END}
{START}
...
...
...
{END}
```

I need the contents that match `{START}` and `{END}` and contain `xyz`

I have tried the following,but it doesnt seem to work,any help on this would be appreciated!!

```
sed '/{START}/xyz/{END}/!d' run.txt
sed '/{START}/,/{END}/!d' run.txt
```

This last command works but it gives all the matches `{START}` and `{END}`

```
awk '/{START}/{p=1};/xyz/p; /{END}/ {p=0}' run.txt
```

I have tried using regex as well but not able to proceed in that as well:

```
v=re.findall(r'{START}(.*xyz){END}',response,re.DOTALL)
```

EDITED:

If the start and end markers are the same for eg., how would it work?

```
    !
    ...
    xyz
    ...
    !
    ...
    ...
    ...
    !
    ..
    <xyz>
    ..
    !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk ' 
    /{START}/{p=1} 
    /xyz/ && p==1{p+=1}
    p>0{str==""?str=$0:str=str"\n"$0}
    /{END}/ && p==2{p=0;print str;str=""}
' run.txt
```

The output would be:

```
{START}
..
<xyz>
..
{END}
{START}
...
xyz
...
...
{END}
```

Brief explanation:

- Use the `p` as the flag to distinguish if `START`, `xyz`, and `END` are found.
- If `{START}` is found, set `p=1`
- If `xyz` is found and only if `p==1`, set the flag `p+=1`
- For each line if `p>0` record the `$0` to `str`
- Print the `str` if finally `{END}` is found, and also reset `p` and `str`

For your new request, set the `START` and `END` to the same pattern. Here's the method,

```
$ awk 'START{p=0}
    /!/{p+=1}
    /xyz/{q=1}
    p>0{str==""?str=$0:str=str"\n"$0}
    p==2{if(q==1){print str;q=0}str="";p=1}
' run_2.txt
!
...
xyz
...
!
..
<xyz>
..
!
```

Comment: Thanks that worked,would the same work for something like this as well:


 
    {START}
    ..
    <xyz>
    ..
    {START}
    ...
    xyz
    ...
    ...
    {START}
    ...
    ...
    ...
    {START}

Comment: @CarmelJacob Edit it in the question and give some description.

Comment: There's much possible situations may be raised. Things became more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it Python like this:

```
with open('path_to_file', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
    split_start = txt.split('{START}')
    split_start = filter(bool, split_start)
    split_end = [i.strip('{END}') for i in split_start]
    results = filter(lambda x: 'xyz' in x, split_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/{START}/{:a;N;/{END}/!ba;/xyz/p}' file
```

Gather up lines between `{START}` and `{END}` and print them if the string contains `xyz`.

If the delimiters are the same use:

```
sed -n '/!/{:a;x;/xyz/p;x;h;:b;n;/!/ba;H;bb}' file
```

This uses the hold space (HS) to gather the lines between the delimiters and prints the HS when it contains the required string.